# Prove that $\Bbb N × \Bbb N$ is countable.

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I am given this problem:

Prove that $\Bbb N × \Bbb N$ is countable by using the function $f(m, n) = 2^m3^n$ and Theorem that says any subset of a countable set is countable.

I'm not exactly sure how the function can be used with the theorem. Would I be able to use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic to show that f is injective? If so, how?

Then, could I say that $f(\Bbb N × \Bbb N)$ is an infinite set of the countable set $\Bbb N$, so then it is therefore countably infinite. Thus, there exists a bijection $g$ (after showing there is an injection) from $\Bbb N × \Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$, therefore $\Bbb N × \Bbb N$ is countably infinite?

Comment: Yes, that must be the intended solution.

Comment: The image of an injective map is bijective with the domain. So you should use the Fund Thm of Arithmetic to show $f$ is injective. Then since the image of $f$ is a subset of the natural numbers, you can use the result that any subset of a countable set is at most countable.

Answer (score 3):

> Would I be able to use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic to show that $f$ is injective?

This proves itself, right? If $2^a3^b=2^c3^d$, what does the FTA say?

> Then, could I say that $f(\Bbb N × \Bbb N)$ is an infinite set of the countable set $\Bbb N$, so then it is therefore countably infinite. Thus, there exists a bijection $g$ (after showing there is an injection) from $\Bbb N × \Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$, therefore $\Bbb N × \Bbb N$ is countably infinite?

It would be clearer to say "$f(\Bbb N × \Bbb N)$ is a subset of the countable set $\Bbb N$..." , but yes, that would be the conclusion. You don't care about is infinity that much, but rather that it's a subset.

Answer (score 0):

Some theorem states that if there is an injection $f:A\to\Bbb N$ then $A$ is at most countable.

Here you just need to show that $f$ is injective;
this is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of arithmetics.

Comment: Okay, but how would I use the Fundamental Theorem to show that?

Comment: if $2^a3^b = 2^c3^d$ then $2^{a-c}=3^{d-b}$ so $2^{a-c} = 3^{d-b}= 1$ so $0 = d-b = a-c$